# What are head and base versions of a git branch

Tags: git, gitlab

We use GitLab.com as our version control and we have a qa branch representing components in qa environment in our repo. When we raise a pull request, we see two versions of qa branch in pull request - qa(base) and qa(head). what is the difference between these two?[image]

Comment: *Git* has no such distinction. I have no idea what GitLab is doing here.

Comment: Is it the same as in [GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58965391/12372506)?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `base` is useless and is on its way out.

The `base` diff shows the version of the target branch from when you created the merge request, instead of showing the target branch in the state that you're actually merging into.

This is explained [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/diffs.html).